# Icon rounded android studio

Tags: android, icons

Qual a diferença  entre o android:icon e o android:icon rounded? 
Não possuir um icon rounded causa algum problema na aplicação?

Answer (score 2):

O [Round Icon](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons) foi introduzido na versão 7.1 (Nougat) do Android. Quando os dispositivos que utilizam esta versão do Android precisam de mostrar o ícone da sua aplicação, eles irão procurar pelo `android:icon` ou `android:roundIcon`.

Por enquanto a omissão do `roundIcon` não causa nenhum problema na aplicação. Mas é recomendado que você comece a incluí-lo, pois num futuro breve maior parte dos dispositivos já estarão a utilizar o Android 7.1. A forma mais fácil de criar um icon redondo é pelo [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html#access), no próprio Android Studio.